# Reducing drawings from 2 MB to 7 or 8 kB in Photoshop CS2 with minimal quality loss?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs2

I like to send drawings to a cartoon vendor, but they require files no larger than 7 or 8 kilobytes. Some of my drawings are 7.8 to 13 megabytes at 8 bit RGB  color in Photoshop CS2. Thank you for your help.

Comment: 7 or 8 kb has no sense. Ask the "Vendor" why he has that nonsense restriction.

Comment: What file format are your drawings in?  What have you tried? What has failed? What size in pixels is the image?  Please [read the guidelines on how to ask questions](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), then edit your question, and add more details. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a typo from them? M and K are next to each other on the keyboard. Maybe it is supposed to be 7-8 MB, not KB?

With how advanced computers even the ones from 10 years ago can handle 10+MB files for printing no sweat.

Comment: No typo, all e-mail files no larger then 8 kb or they will not receive them...

Comment: @Carlo - so send them a plain text email which will surely be under 8kb, but with a link to download the image from an image sharing website.  There's no need to put images in emails.  Also, why did you not add this information to your question, as requested?

Comment: e-mailed the vender, it was a typo and they corrected it. it now reads as follows,   All files must be under 8 MB or we will not receive them. If your files are larger than that, please spread them across multiple emails. Sorry for the confusion,

Comment: @Carlo - you can still send them a 13mb (or even larger) file if you follow my advice to send a link in the email to an image shared on an image sharing service. You don't have to do anything to your image at all.

Comment: The question is based on an irrational misconception. It has some value as the statue of not so good communication. Unfortunately some can think that it contains a method to compress images losslessly to 1...0,1% of the original size.

Comment: Thanks Billy Kerr, I'll give it a try, I must have given some people a headache with my question. sorry for that confusion. This is my First time asking for help...  again many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can not. **This filesize has no sense**.

An image of 7-8 kb is a miniature of about 50px50px.

This is not even good for a thumbnail. Probably it is good for an emoticon.

Here is a sample.

[image]

[Original image](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/worker-with-doubts_834551.htm#term=cartoon&page=1&position=24)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, The size 9.027 wide x 13.063 Height inches, or 2708 x 3919 Pixels at 300 ppi resolution.

Comment: That is your original. Which is not important. The file size the "vendor" is asking is then around 60px wide x 40px height. You have your information wrong... Or most likely, he has.

Comment: @Rafael  - the OP has now said it's the email that has to be under 8kb, not the file size. So, basically we are all wasting our time here trying to answer something which could easily have been cleared up, if he had taken the trouble to add this crucial detail to his question.